# Clear All textBoxes (Any Shortcut)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have several textboxes for inputs and then several more for results.
Is there any shortcut to clear all the entries on form?

for example `aTextBox.Clear();`

Comment: The only way I am aware of to accomplish this is to recursively iterate through the control tree, check the type, and clear the control.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811229/how-to-clear-the-text-of-all-textboxes-in-the-form

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all the text boxes are direct children of your form, you can use LINQ:

```
yourForm.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().ForEach(textBox => textBox.Clear());
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to loop on all form controls and check if type is textbox, then .Text = string.empty

Comment: consider implementing this as an extension method.

Comment: also, as a deleted comment mentioned, you need to also check all the container controls on the form.

Comment: Yes, and this will lead to nested loops, so @Frédéric answer is better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034161/clear-all-textboxes-any-shortcut/7034178#7034178

Comment: no, this will lead to a recursive function.  if you're using nested loops here you've taken the wrong road.

Comment: And Freddy's code doesn't even address textboxes within container controls.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cntrlCollections = GetAll(this,typeof(TextBox));

       foreach (Control ctrl in cntrlCollections)
        {

            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                ctrl.Text = " ";
            }
        }      

public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control, Type type)
    {
        var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

        return controls.SelectMany(ctrl=>GetAll(ctrl,type)).Concat(controls).Where
               (c=>c.GetType() ==type);
    }
```

Call this function like above in a click event to clear all textboxes. Hope this will helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Commenting Frederic - you need to use ActiveForm `yourform.ActiveForm.Controls. ...`.

Beacuse `yourform.Controls. ...` drops an error:

`An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Controls.get`

Apply to VS2012Express