# hide "all" textboxes together when button is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

How to hide "all" textboxes together when button is clicked? Is there any short method to avoid hiding them one by one?

```
gamma_textBox.Visible = false;
```

Comment: asp.net ? winforms? wpf?

Comment: this question is very common, is like. [How to clear the text of all textBoxes in the form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811229/how-to-clear-the-text-of-all-textboxes-in-the-form)

Comment: @spajce i wanted an easy way just like the code below. and also i didn't see that question although i searched! sorry

Comment: no, its okay, it happen sometimes `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach(var tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) tb.Visible = false;
```

But note this will not look *inside* any containers. You can do so recursively though by enumerating each child's `Controls` collection. An example of this would be:

```
public void HideChildTextBoxes(Control parent)
{
    foreach(Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        HideChildTextBoxes(c);
        if(c is TextBox) c.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: when I use the first code you wrote it says:
Error 1 Foreach cannot operate on a 'method group'. Did you intend to invoke the 'method group'?

Comment: @bunNyBug Forgot the parentheses. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this generic, recursive method:

```
private void ProcessAllControls<T>(Control rootControl, Action<T> action)where T:Control
{
    foreach (T childControl in rootControl.Controls.OfType<T>())
    {
        action(childControl);
    }
    foreach (Control childControl in rootControl.Controls)
    {
        ProcessAllControls<T>(childControl, action);
    }
}
```

It works this way:

```
ProcessAllControls<TextBox>(this, txt=> txt.Visible = false);
```

This method searches recursively all child controls of a given container control for controls of a specified type. Then it applies an action(in this case it changes `Visibility)`.

If you want it for any kind of control, use the non-generic overload:

```
public static void ProcessAllControls(Control rootControl, Action<Control> action)
{
    foreach (Control childControl in rootControl.Controls)
    {
        ProcessAllControls(childControl, action);
        action(childControl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you using Winforms, you can do it like;

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
{
   if (this.Controls[i].GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox")
       this.Controls[i].Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: -1 because this answer doesn't add any value to the question because @lc has already provided the same answer only more concise.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Thanks for the downvote. But you are quite wrong. In Stackoverflow history, there are a lot of nearly answers in the same question. But this doesn't (shouldn't) affect the giving the right answer either. lc's answers and mine are quite different. Check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94004/same-answers-should-be-deleted-in-stack-overflow

Comment: While this would work, I personally like to avoid string comparisons if at all possible. Additionally, this will *not* hide any subclassed textboxes.

Comment: @lc. Yes, you are right. But since OP doesn't said anyting about subclasses, he shouldn't except people can read his mind. Right?

Comment: +1 Soner Gonul's answer is quite right it's not a matter of personal likes or dislikes if it provides the correct outcome which in fact it does, then this should be a upvoted answer it's up to the OP to select which answer he `Selects` based on his or her understanding. the foreach is another way of doing a for loop and this answer in my opinion does meet the standards of another viable answer for example `Tim Schmelter` provided a working solution based on A Generic Method vs the same correct answer provided by Ic both achieve the same outcome.

Comment: @SonerGönül Agreed. I was simply pointing it out. It may even be a feature in a given application if they only want non-subclassed objects.

Answer (score 1):

Paste them into panel(or other container), and set visibility of that panel.

Comment: +1 this is in general a good way to go about organizing controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all textbox into a **LIST(Or array)**,then use a for iteration to make them invisiable.

Comment: That's like buying a bus ticket then walking to work.. better to get at the control thru the Controls using a foreach loop and recursively calling and checking the control by it' Type look at @Ic. answer