# C# reset textbox to default value

Tags: winforms, reset

I want have reset control like webforms but in winform.
in form design the controls have a default value. I want when user edit the controls, after press a reset button, the controls get their default values.
after i searched in internet I found ResetText() method, but unfortunately I didn't find good example for it.
if you know about it please let me know. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear the text of all textBoxes in the form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811229/how-to-clear-the-text-of-all-textboxes-in-the-form)

Comment: but I don't want clear their content. I just want undo their default values.

Comment: You could store the default value in the `Tag` property, then on click, set `Text` = `Tag`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each control have a property as "Tag", just need fill your default value in Tag. then write below code on "reset" button:

```
private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtSearch.Text= txtSearch.Tag.ToString();
    }
```

finally thanks  @Danny Beckett  for his answer!!