# C# Iterating over known textboxes from array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to iterate over textboxes from a string in `string` Array

```
static string[] TextBoxes = {
                             "EmpName",
                             "Sales",
                             "BasePay",
                             "Commission",
                             "GrossPay",
                             "Deductions",
                             "Housing",
                             "FoodAndClothing",
                             "Entertainment",
                             "Misc"
                            };
```

Each of the above are parts of the form for example txtHousing is the housing input element. And so on and so forth.

And the iteration takes place here

```
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (byte i = 0; i < TextBoxes.Length; i++)
    {
        this["txt" + TextBoxes[i]].Text = "";
    }
    this.txtEmpName.Focus();
}
```

Except I'm getting a strange "error" for this `System.String` can we not call objects like this from the `this` object?

Just read a source saying that this.getProperty may work so I'll try that.

**Error**

Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Pay_Calculator.PayCalculator'

Comment: I don't know if it would matter, but I have only ever seen `int i = 0....`. Perhaps that's the issue? Or perhaps it's just something new for me

Comment: What is `this["txt" + TextBoxes[i]].Text = "";` supposed to do? What is `this[string]` supposed to return? - not enough code to tell...

Comment: It's suppose to clear the text input so this.txtDeductions.Text= "". Kind of thought it was clear enough for people here.

Comment: And byte is smaller than int so byte is more wise.

Comment: Please share the complete error you are receiving.

Comment: Your problem is using this["myProperty"].  That is a JavaScript convention.  You can make your class an Indexer, but it will only accept an int index to access properties.  (Well, apparently you can do indexer overloading to use named indexers but I've never used it.)

Comment: Yeah well coming from Javascript to C# I'm sure you understand where I thought I could get away with that lol.

Comment: Yeah, C# is moving that direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use Reflection/Dynamic object.

```
var me = (dynamic) this;
foreach (var name in TextBoxes)
{
  ((TextBox) me['txt' + name]).Value = string.Empty;
}
```

Another solution is to recurse over all controls, then you don't need to name all the text boxes.

```
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ClearTextBox(this);
}

void ClearTextBox (Control c)
{
    var t = c as Textbox;
    if (t != null)
       t.Value = string.Empty;
    foreach (var child in c.Controls)
       ClearTextBox(child);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do something like this

```
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (byte i = 0; i < TextBoxes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (this.Controls.ContainsKey("txt" + TextBoxes[i]))
        {
            TextBox txtBox = this.Controls["txt" + TextBoxes[i]] as TextBox;
            if (txtBox != null)
            {
                // Do your Stuff
                txtBox.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works if the parent of the `TextBoxes` is the form itself  If a `TextBox` is in a panel then this fails.

Comment: and you can use `byte` which is smaller in memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **WinForms**, change `static` to `private` and use [Controls.Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
    private string[] TextBoxes = {
                         "EmpName",
                         "Sales",
                         "BasePay",
                         "Commission",
                         "GrossPay",
                         "Deductions",
                         "Housing",
                         "FoodAndClothing",
                         "Entertainment",
                         "Misc"
                        };


    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string name in TextBoxes)
        {
            TextBox tb = this.Controls.Find("txt" + name, true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.Text = "";
            }
        }
        this.txtEmpName.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to loop through the controls and check whether the control is a text box, later you can check the name of the control to match your array element and clear it.

You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811229/how-to-clear-the-text-of-all-textboxes-in-the-form) example