# Clear all textboxes at once in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

Is there a way to clear textboxes at once when they have been renamed as `txtFName`, `txtMName` etc... They may have variety of names beginning with `txt`. Is this possible? Something like

```
private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtFname.Clear();
    txtLName.Clear();
    txtUsername.Clear();
    txtPasswrd.Clear();
    /*So many textboxes to be cleared*/
}
```

to be replaced with

```
private void ClearTextboxes(object obj)
{
    /*codes to clear textboxes*/
}
```

and then we can call it in the button click event

```
private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClearTextboxes();
    txtFname.Focus();
}
```

Comment: @RB Its only a duplicate if he is using WPF. OP Are you using WPF or WinForms?

Comment: @CathalMF This question has been asked many times. Here is a WinForms equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811229/how-to-clear-the-text-of-all-textboxes-in-the-form. A quick search would have found the OP many other examples.

Comment: WPF? WinForms? WebForms? ASP.NET MVC? SilverLight? ...?

Comment: Forgot to mention. I am using a win form application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this method clear all textbox from WinForm

```
void ClearTextboxes(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection ctrls)
    {
       foreach (Control ctrl in ctrls)
       {
          if (ctrl is TextBox)
              ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;
          ClearTextboxes(ctrl.Controls);
       }
    }
```

and you can call it

```
private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClearTextboxes();
    txtFname.Focus();
}
```

Comment: In ClearInputs(ctrl.Controls); ............ClearInputs means what?

Comment: sorry it was a silly mistake `ClearInputs` will be `ClearTextboxes`  the method name itself,  its recursively clear controls, name was remain my version

Comment: eidited now correct one

Comment: Your ClearTextboxes() can't be called that way. It needs an argument: an object of class System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection. How do I initiate that?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all textbox in your VisualTree like this:

```
foreach (TextBox txtBx in FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(this))
{
    txtBx.Clear();
}
```

FindVisualChildren :

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As an argument you can pass any parent it can be StackPanel, or Grid or whole window.

Comment: `VisualTreeHelper` assumes WPF. Is this WPF?

Comment: I meant the question, not your answer. Also, [don't copy answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type), or at least not without attribution.

Answer (score 0):

One way using event is:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace textBoxs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Subscribe();
        }

        private event Action ClearAll;

        void Subscribe()
        {
            ClearAll += tbA.Clear;
            ClearAll += tbB.Clear;
            ClearAll += tbC.Clear;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearAll();
        }
    }
}
```