# How to Bold text in richtextbox if there are more than 1 richtextbox?

Tags: c#

Here is my code when there is a one `richtextbox` only. However, I do not know how to tackle with more than one `richtextbox`.

```
private void BoldToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new font(currentFont.FontFamily, FontStyle.Bold);
}
```

Comment: @rene  
Thank you so much. I get a direction from you to solve my issue.

Comment: ToolStripItem makes this easy, it doesn't change the selected control when it is clicked.  So you can use `this.ActiveControl as RichTextBox` to find the control back.  Make it even prettier by using the Application.Idle event to disable the item when the wrong control is selected or when the RTB does not have any text selected yet.

Answer (score 2):

The [`ActiveControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your form will save you. When the Click event of your toolstripbutton is fired, the ActiveControl still holds a reference to the control that just lost focus. This Click implementation of your toolstripbutton will work:

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // check if the active control (held by the Form) was a RichTextbox
    var rtb = this.ActiveControl as RichTextBox;
    if (rtb != null)
    {
        // if it is, do the right thing
        rtb.SelectionFont = new Font(rtb.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
}
```

This is what it might look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Along similar lines to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811229/how-to-clear-the-text-of-all-textboxes-in-the-form) you could do something like this

```
 private void BoldTextBoxes()
 {
     Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;

     func = (controls) =>
         {
             foreach (Control control in controls)
                 if (control is RichTextBox)
                     (control as RichTextBox).SelectionFont = new font(currentFont.FontFamily, FontStyle.Bold);
                 else
                     func(control.Controls);
         };

     func(Controls);
 }
```

Comment: This will bold all selections in all richtextboxes, that is not what the OP asks.

Answer (score -1):

Quite easy:

```
    private void BoldToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new font(currentFont.FontFamily, FontStyle.Bold);
    richTextBox2.SelectionFont = new font(currentFont.FontFamily, FontStyle.Bold);
    richTextBox3.SelectionFont = new font(currentFont.FontFamily, FontStyle.Bold);
    // Continue
    }
```

Comment: They don't want to bold the font in all controls, they have selected text in one of their controls, click the menuitem, then want to bold the text in the correct control. That is not quite easy.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. As I saw the other solutions, I realized I misinterpreted the question.