# Clear Winform text boxes code snippet explanation

Tags: c#, winforms, lambda

new to c#

I'm trying to clear all text boxes in a winform, this code snippet from:

[How to clear the text of all textBoxes in the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811229/how-to-clear-the-text-of-all-textboxes-in-the-form)

does the job but can someone explain to me what it's doing?

```
private void ClearTextBoxes()
{
    Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;

    func = (controls) =>
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls)
            if (control is TextBox)
                (control as TextBox).Clear();
            else
                func(control.Controls);
    };

    func(Controls);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;` is declaring a delegate that takes as an argument a `Control.ControlCollection`.

`func = (controls) =>    {... }` assigns the delegate an anonymous method body that performs the action inside `{...}` when executed.

`func(Controls);` executes the delegate, passing in the form's `Controls` collection which contains all of the top-level controls in the form.

The method body of the anonymous method enumerates the controls in the ControlCollection passed in, and clears all text boxes.  For controls that are not `TextBox` controls, it recurses into itself and checks controls that are contained by the control.  This way if there is a `GroupBox` or some other control container, the children of those controls get searched for TextBoxes.

This could be rewritten simpler (avoiding delegates and anonymous methods) by doing the following:

```
private void ClearTextBoxes()
{
    ClearTextBoxes(Controls);
}

private void ClearTextBoxes(Control.ControlCollection controls) {
    foreach (Control control in controls)
        if (control is TextBox)
            (control as TextBox).Clear();
        else
            ClearTextBoxes(control.Controls);
};
```

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful

Answer (score 2):

func is a lambda function that recursively traverses the ControllCollection. For every item it encounters it checks if the item is a TextBox. If it is, the TextBox is cleared, otherwise the control is a ControlCollection of its own and the function calls itself again.

If the lambda notation throws you off you can also look at it this way:

```
private void ClearTextBoxes(){
    ClearTextBoxOrContinue(Controls);
}

private void ClearTextBoxOrContinue(Control.ControllCollection controls){
    // iterate over every control in controls (the 'children' of controls)
    foreach (Control thisControl in controls)
        if (thisControl is TextBox)
        // if it is a TextBox, clear it
            (thisControl as TextBox).Clear();
        else
            // else, iterate over thisControl's children (and/or grandchildren...) 
            ClearTextBoxOrContinue(thisControl.Controls);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This Helped