# How can i clear a textbox after i prompt a messagebox of error?

Tags: c#, textbox, messagebox

I've been looking for a way to solve this. I want to clear the two textbox after I have exited the messagebox prompt. This is what i have tried so far.

```
if (mushroom.Checked == false && extracheese.Checked == false && sausage.Checked == false && pepperoni.Checked == false && onion.Checked == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("PLEASE CHOOSE YOUR TOPPINGS!", "Hot Pizza", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            ordersumm.Clear();
            totalcost.Clear();

        }
```

I have also tried this method posted here but it prompts two message boxes

```
    private void value(object sender, EventArgs e)
  if MessageBox.Show("PLEASE CHOOSE YOUR TOPPINGS!", "Hot Pizza", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error) == DialogResult.OK)
 {
   ordersumm.TextChanged -= value;
   ordersumm.Clear();
   ordersumm.TextChanged += value;
   totalcost.TextChanged -= value;
   totalcost.Clear();
   totalcost.TextChanged += value;
   return;
 }
```

Again, how can I make it possible to clear the two text box (ordersumm and totalcost) at once after this message box prompt?
thanks!

Comment: `ordersumm.Text = string.Empty;` etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear the text of all textBoxes in the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811229/how-to-clear-the-text-of-all-textboxes-in-the-form)

Comment: On another note, limit the question to one issue, not multiple please.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set an Empty or null value to the textbox:

```
ordersumm.Text = string.Empty;
```

OR

```
ordersumm.Text = "";
```

Regards,
LA.

Comment: This wouldnt solve his problem with recurring message boxes, since this would also trigger his event and pop up the msg box.